# Having issue with XBRL API OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, python-requests, xbrl, sec

Has anyone worked with the XBRL API for financial data (https://xbrlus.github.io/xbrl-api/)? I am able to use the interactive demo but not able to recreate it on my own and successfully access the API using the python requests library when accessing the oauth2.

This is what I am trying now, which returns an "invalid request" error. Appreciate any support.

```
import requests

body_auth = {'username' : 'email@domain', 
            'client_id': 'generated from the XBRL API demo', 
            'client_secret' : 'generated from the XBRL API demo', 
            'password' : 'password', 
            'grant_type' : 'password'}

payload = urlencode(body_auth)
url = 'https://api.xbrl.us/oauth2/token'
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

res = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
auth_json = res.json()
auth_json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I modify your code to add:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlencode
```

and

```py
res.raise_for_status()
```

I get:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.xbrl.us/oauth2/token
```

I assume that this is what you are seeing when you say "invalid request" ?

If I then update `username`, `client_id`, `client_secret` and `password` with my own credentials, your code works without further modification.

It's odd that this is resulting in a `400` error rather than a `401`, but I would infer that there is an issue with the credentials that you are using rather than the code.